# Check when string contains only special characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string, special-characters

So what I want to do is check if the string contains only special characters.
An example should make it clear

```
Hello -> Valid
Hello?? -> Valid
?? -> Not Valid
```

Same thing done for all special characters including `"."`

Comment: did underscore a special character?

Answer (score 9):

You can use this regex with anchors to check if your input contains **only** non-word (special) characters:

```
^\W+$
```

If underscore also to be treated a special character then use:

```
^[\W_]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX8pE7/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> def spec(s):
        if not re.match(r'^[_\W]+$', s):
            print('Valid')
        else:
            print('Invalid')


>>> spec('Hello')
Valid
>>> spec('Hello??')
Valid
>>> spec('??')
Invalid
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks so much for adding the code. For downvotes I think some people may have their own reasons for doing so though I appreciate some comments.

Comment: In OP's perspective `Hello??` is a valid string but your pattern only match `??`https://regex101.com/r/iX8pE7/1

Comment: @Kasra: You didn't copy full regex from my answer. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX8pE7/2)

Comment: @Kasra i edited his code... At first he posted the regex only, later i added some codes.

Comment: @Kasra yep, it won't match , that's why i added **if not** . You could switch the print statements according to the conditions.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes! your code is right! sorry i miss that!

Comment: @anubhava i miss Avinash's edit! can you edit your code till i could remove the down vote?

Comment: @Kasra That sad moment when you downvote without thinking and then ask the OP to edit! :(

Comment: @BhargavRao I think i down vote in a same time with edit! any way i accept  my mistake nicely!

Comment: @Kasra Yep! That is the right way. Now waiting for the other downvoter to comment!

Comment: @anubhava Adding the demo you mentioned in the comments to the answer would have been a worthwhile edit :)

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao, I added demo in my answer.

Comment: np. Good to see you answering python regex too (had seen you answering java only) . Python now has another RegExPert in it's kitty :)

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao, Java is still my core area. Recently I started learning Python so I am very much a newbie there.

Comment: But you know RegEx! Copying from AvinashRaj's profile *If you know regex well, then you could touch any of the popular SO tags*! :)

Comment: Oh that's right @AvinashRaj has become a real RegEx Ninja on SO

Answer (score 5):

You can use a costume python function :

```
>>> import string 
>>> def check(s):
...   return all(i in string.punctuation for i in s)
```

[string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) contain all special characters and you can use `all` function to check if all of the characters are special!

Comment: Adding a link to the module would be better

Comment: It will return True for empty string, so be cautious.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
import string

def checkString(your_string):
    for let in your_string.lower():
        if let in string.ascii_lowercase:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

s = input("Enter a string:")

if all(i in string.punctuation for i in s):
    print ("Only special characters")

else:
    print ("Valid")
```

use the above loop to set boolean events and use it accordingly